# Not getting location updates

Tags: android, android-location

In my map application I dont seem to be getting location updates, I got in the car and started driving around but my position marker never changed on the map and even gave me a `null lat and long`

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if(provider == null){
        provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    }
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 60000, 5, this);
```

my onLocationChanged listener

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Logging logger = new Logging();
    logger.append("V", className, "onLocationChanged(Fine)", "Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());

    try {
        userLat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
        userLong = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        int mLat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1000000);
        int mLng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1000000);

        userLocation = new GeoPoint(mLat, mLng);

        if (!initialFix && mapSettingShowLoc) {
            showUserLocation(userLocation);
            initialFix = true;
        }

        if (mapSettingShowLoc) {
            showUserLocation(userLocation);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.append("E", className, "onLocationChanged", "Exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

in my `onResume` i register to listen again because I can start a new activity from the map

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, this);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So are you getting location updates at all? Also as an aside I noticed that in the first block you are asking for "coarse" updates (Network) every 60 seconds at 2 meters and in the the onresume you are asking for the GPS at 2 seconds and 1 meter.  Out of experience I would ask specifically for what you want GPS, NETWORK, or both and not leave it up to the system (many implementations use the network when they should use GPS and vice versa, this is device dependent)

Comment: What happens when you launch Google Maps at the same time? Does that work OK?

Comment: yes google maps works fine, I use it nearly everyday. the only time I get a location change is on first run of the activity. If i navigate away to a new activity calling `removeUpdates` in my `onPause` then as you see how my resume is, I do not get another call to the `onLocationChange` after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it was because of the miss-matched providers that I had